# Cleveref: cleveref appears to not be so clever (sorry for the pun but I couldn't help myself)

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

[image]

This didn't happen when I wasn't using `cleveref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCr}
  \ddot{x} - 2\Omega\dot{y} - \Omega^2x & = &
  -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}(x + \pi_2r_{12}) - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}(x - \pi_1r_{12})
  \label{xjacobi}\\
  \ddot{y} + 2\Omega\dot{x} - \Omega^2y & = &
  -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}y - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}y\label{yjacobi}\\
  \ddot{z} & = & -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}z - \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}z\label{zjacobi}
\end{IEEEeqnarray}
Let's multiple \cref{xjacobi} by \(\dot{x}\), \cref{yjacobi} by \(\dot{y}\), and \cref{zjacobi} by \(\dot{z}\).
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Also, *what* didn't happen?

Comment: You code produces errors. Please turn it into a proper MWE. Also, there's no `\cref` commands?

Comment: Please  fix your document, I get ! Undefined control sequence.
l.7   \ddot{x} - 2\varOmega

Comment: Until you make a workable example we don't know what _it_ is.

Comment: Please _test_ the code you post and make it run without error. ! Undefined control sequence.
\@IEEEeqnarrayXCR ...@eqnsw \if@IEEEissubequation

Comment: @dustin It really isn't worth looking at a pdf if you get tex errors and anyway you need to explicitly say that you get those errors if you expect someone else to look.

Comment: But you didn't say the MWE generated an error _at all_ I (and most other people offering help) just stop at the first error and ask you to fix the example. If you get a TeX error you don't know how to fix you should ask about _that_ and then the MWE is an example of the described problem (and any pdf output is largely irrelevant)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle we had a miscommunication. I planned on figuring out that error myself that is why I neglected it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, let's see, first the [manual of `cleveref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/cleveref), in the non-bugs section,

> `cleveref` will not work properly with the standard LaTeX `eqnarray` environment.
>   There is no intention to fix this. The `eqnarray` environment is poorly
>   implemented, making it difficult to get it to work properly with `cleveref`,
>   and it's broken any way. You're *far* better off using the `amsmath` replacements,
>   such as `gather`, `align`, `multline` and `split`, which *do* work properly
>   with `cleveref`. (See http://www.tug.org/pracjourn/2006-4/madsen/).

Then, [ieeetran manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/ieeetran),

> Perhaps the most convenient and popular way to produce
>   multiline equations is LaTeX2ε’s `eqnarray` environment.
>   However, `eqnarray` has several serious shortcomings:[...]

Nope.

Anyway, use something other than IEEEeqnarray.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[noabbrev]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{3}
  \ddot{x} - 2\Omega\dot{y} - \Omega^2x & = -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}(x + \pi_2r_{12}) &- \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}(x - \pi_1r_{12})
  \label{xjacobi}\\
  \ddot{y} + 2\Omega\dot{x} - \Omega^2y & =   -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}y &- \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}y\label{yjacobi}\\
  \ddot{z} & =  -\frac{\mu_1}{r_1^3}z &- \frac{\mu_2}{r_2^3}z\label{zjacobi}
\end{alignat}

\Cref{xjacobi,yjacobi,zjacobi}, \Cref{xjacobi}, \cref{yjacobi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So only multiline labeled equation fail then in equation arrays.  Thanks.

Comment: @doncherry Thanks for the formatting. It's much better.