# cleveref vs. IEEEtrantools/IEEEeqnarray

Tags: cross-referencing, amsmath, ieeetran, cleveref

It seems that it is not that easy to get IEEEtrantools and cleveref to work together [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227137/how-to-use-cleveref-with-ieeeeqnarray),[2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132823/ieeetrantools-clash-with-cleveref),[3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250733/ieeetran-cls-and-cleveref-the-special-case-of-ieeeeqnarray),[4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119225/cleveref-cleveref-appears-to-not-be-so-clever-sorry-for-the-pun-but-i-couldnt)].

My question is of a somewhat more general nature: Is it actually worth the effort?

cleveref clearly is a fantastic package, and I will definitely not refrain from using it. To typeset equations properly, eqnarray is outdated, and AMS align does not satisfy my needs. I have some equations where LHS and RHS are multi-lined, and they should both be aligned to their respective side of the equation sign. (I hope you know what I mean.) This is only doable in AMS align with hacks like using \quad to "more or less" make it look nice. IEEEtrantools, on the other hand, provides this functionality.

Should I stop using IEEEtrantools? I really like the package, but it seems nearly impossible to get it to work with cleveref.

Comment: This question will provoke opinion-based answers ;-)